# Dynamic data filtering regex

Tags: regex

I have a file containing the order of personnel in many departments as follows:

```
L1: Member1 (0981234567); L2: Member2 (0981234568); L3: Member3 (0981234569)
L1: Member1 (0981234567); L2: Member2 (0981234567), Member3 (0981234567); L3: Member4 (0981234567)
L1: Member1 (0981234527); L2: Member2 (0981244567), Member3 (0921234567), Member4 (0981234567); L3: Member5 (0981254567)
```

I need to write a regex to filter all lines with the above structure. I tried:

```
L1: [a-zA-Z0-9]{3,15} \([0-9]{10}\); L2: [a-zA-Z0-9]{3,15} \([0-9]{10}\); L3: [a-zA-Z0-9]{3,15} \([0-9]{10}\)
```

But the problem is that my data L2 can have 1, 2 or 3 people, I don't know how to handle these cases, please help me.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can optionally repeat that member part for L2. If you also want that for L1 and L3, you can reuse the same mechanism.

```
L1: [a-zA-Z0-9]{3,15} \([0-9]{10}\); L2: [a-zA-Z0-9]{3,15} \([0-9]{10}\)(?:, [a-zA-Z0-9]{3,15} \([0-9]{10}\))*; L3: [a-zA-Z0-9]{3,15} \([0-9]{10}\)*
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3JUrI0/1)

If the order of L1, L2 and L3 is already ok, you might shorten it to a repeating pattern and use `\d` or `\d+` to match the digits of `L`

```
^(?:L\d: [a-zA-Z0-9]{3,15} \([0-9]{10}\)(?:, [a-zA-Z0-9]{3,15} \([0-9]{10}\))*(?:; |$))+
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SZ0lUe/1)

Comment: Thanks you, but how do I get member information by level, (L1 -> list member level 1, L2 -> list member level 2...) Do I need to use regex to output the string 'L1:Member1 (0981234527)' and process the string to remove the extra characters

Comment: @Joe That depends on the tool or language, but it might be easier to match what you want and then after process it, getting the exact parts that you want. If you have a single member, you can use a single capture group to get `0981234527` for example. If you have multiple numbers for the same level, it depends on the tool or language what the capabilities are.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:-

```
/^(?:L[1-3]: (?:[a-z\d]{3,15} \(\d{10}\), )*[a-z\d]{3,15} \(\d{10}\)(?:; |$))+$/gmi
```